# bootstrap tooltip dont invoke child

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Let's say I have these tags:

```
<ul data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="hello world">
    <li data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="content 1">content 1</li>
    <li data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="content 2">content 2</li>
    <li data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="content 3">content 3</li>
</ul>
```

How do I prevent tooltip of `ul` showing when hover over `li` tag? Currently when I hover over `li` both tooltip are showing.

Comment: Given that hovering over the list items means you're also hovering over the unordered list itself, I'm not sure what it is you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: ok, so `li` is hidden by default, then when i click on `ul`, `li`s is shown. I want when hover over shown `li`, only tooltip that belongs to that `li` is showing, `ul` tooltip stay hidden. like `stopPropagation()` but i dont know how to do that

Comment: @DarielPratama How is `ul` clicked if initially hidden ?

Comment: @DarielPratama That's not really possible with just data- attributes. You'd have to add and destroy the tooltips when toggling the ul: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-methods

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the case, but you could use the [tooltip methods](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-methods):

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

$('li').hover(
  function () {
    $('ul').tooltip('hide');
}, function () {
    $('ul').tooltip('show');
});
```

```css
body { padding-top: 50px }
ul {
    padding: 20px;
    background: red;
}
li {
    padding: 20px;
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="hello world">
    <li data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="content 1">content 1</li>
    <li data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="content 2">content 2</li>
    <li data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="content 3">content 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to the accepted answer that works with nth-child `.tooltip()` scenarios:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tt = $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]');
    tt.tooltip();
    tt.on('show.bs.tooltip', function (e) {
        tt.not($(this)).tooltip('hide');
    });
});
```

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
 body {
  padding: 50px;
}
ul {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px dashed steelblue;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="hello world">
    <li data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="content 1"><a data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="link!">content 1</a></li>
    <li data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="content 2">content 2</li>
    <li data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="content 3">content 3</li>
</ul>
```